# Метод аутентификации на основе неподсматриваемого пароля

Tags: защита, пароль, методы

Здравствуйте! Задали тему для РГЗ по Защите информации - Нужно написать программу, демонстрирующую работу метода аутентификации на основе неподсматриваемого пароля. Что за метод такой? Можете подсказать источники для ознакомления с этим методом? Спасибо.

Comment: На каком языке надо написать то?

Comment: "Неподсматриваемый" может быть и при помощи снифера. Это может быть аутентификация методами challenge-answer, где передаётся не пароль, а вычисленный с участием пароля ответ.

Comment: К ответу комментарий добавлять уже не получается :( Если ключ один и тот же для разных сессий, то надёжность метода после нескольких сеансов внушает опасения. Ну да пускай. Зачёт, как я понимаю, уже получен? :)))

Comment: Да уже красуется в зачетке:) Да эт верно что опасения) Если в реале делать для какой нить с системы, и серьезно отнестись, то можно было бы все продумать... А так.. конечно же и здесь все от балды не делалось, но много чего еще надо, чтобы запустить в какую нить систему...

Answer (score 1):

Своими мыслями была решена проблема так:
 1. Перед пользователем появляется окно, на котором расположены ячейки или рисунки с числовым содержанием.
 2. Ячейки содержат цифры, полученные рандомом.
 3. Далее пользователь зная кодовую комбинацию, отмечает в окне ячейками область в которой содержится один из символов кода, или весь код.
 4. Программа читает содержимое отмеченной области, и вы дает пользователю, либо разрешение на вход, либо отказ в идентификации.
 [image: пример]

Comment: Боюсь, что преподаватель лоханулся. При перехвате снифером запроса и ответа код восстанавливается (возможно частично). При challenge-answer (а таких аутентификаций много) восстановить однозначно по (1) одному ответу невозможно (множество паролей, дающих на выходе один ответ м.б. большим) (2) вычислять нужно долго (года, десятилетия, века, ...)

Comment: Ээээ что Вы имеете ввиду?) Почему лоханулся?)

Comment: Если я правильно понял решение, то код, возможно частично, отображается в запросе. Случайным образом формируется обрамление. Пользователь сообщает участок, где содержится код или его часть. Набрав некоторое количество запросов/ответов можно вычислить код. Если бы в формировании запроса участвовали однонаправленные функции, так что сам код не передавался, то шансы на его расшифровку были бы ниже.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под запросом?) Если как связь с БД, то нету её тут) Эт же РГЗ) Внутри кода задана последовательность символов - ключ. Пользователь кликает по области, т.е как вы говорите сообщает участок где содержится код или его часть. Но мы сделали чтоб в не смотря на то что в области может содержаться и весь, программа принимает тока один символ. Приняла перешла к другому и так далее. + Стоит ограничение на число кликов в программе, чтобы исключить возможность подбора ключа. Вот такая вот схема...

Comment: Запрос - не к базе данных, а в терминах "запрос-ответ (chell-resp)". Если я правильно понял (?) в запросе ключ (пароль) передаётся в том или ином формате (возможно в виде изображения). Но фиксируя обмен между пользователем и системой (по сети?) этот ключ восстановить можно (пусть и при помощи человека, т.е. не программно). Вот это я имел в виду. Хотелось бы понять, правильно ли я понял ситуацию.

Comment: А ну если быть уже конкретным, то суть такая:
есть ключ, из 6 символов.
При старте программы счетчик просматриваемого символа =1.
Затем пользователь кликая по ячейка, отмечает область, и программа смотрит каждый символ в отмеченной области, и проверяет его с текущим символом в ключе.
Если таков есть, счетчик увеличивается, т.е. переходим к след символу, и пользователю снова нужно отметить область. И в таком духе пока счетчик не станет равным длине ключа.

Answer (score 0):

Осмелюсь предположить, что это типа авторизации в unix подобных системах - когда вводишь пароль, он не отображается на экране (даже звездочки не отображаются). На деле это выглядит примерно следующим образом:

Login: User

Password:

Login OK...